# Using if else condition to show elements on RectJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some menu items I want to show according to user roles. I have 2 user roles form the database `(1 for admin and 0 for normal user)`. But my code always return the menu items for  normal user even if its an admin who is logged in.
I am also storing user details in a `useContext` and calling them on every component

Kindly Help

My Code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Menubar.css";
import { UserContext } from "../../UserContext";

const Menubar = () => {

const user = React.useContext(UserContext);

console.warn(user.role)

return (
<div>
  <div className="appBottomMenu">

    {user.role === 1 ? (
      <Link to="/admin/home" className="item" tabIndex="1">
        <div className="col">
          <i className="fi fi-rr-home"></i>
        </div>
      </Link>
    ) : (
      <Link to="/" className="item" tabIndex="1">
        <div className="col">
          <i className="fi fi-rr-home"></i>
        </div>
      </Link>
    )}

    {user.role === 1 ? (
      <Link className="item" to="/admin/farmers">
        <div className="col">
          <i className="fi fi-rr-users"></i>
        </div>
      </Link>
    ) : (
      <Link to="/area" className="item" tabIndex="1">
        <div className="col">
          <i className="fi fi-rr-marker"></i>
        </div>
      </Link>
    )}

    <Link to="/community" className="item">
      <div className="col">
        <i className="fi fi-rr-browser"></i>
      </div>
    </Link>


    {user.role === 1 ? (
      <Link className="item" to="/admin/farms">
        <div className="col">
          <i className="fi fi-rr-users"></i>
        </div>
      </Link>
    ) : (
      <Link to="/shop" className="item">
        <div className="col">
          <i className="fi fi-rr-shopping-cart"></i>
        </div>
      </Link>
    )}


    <Link to="/profile" className="item">
      <div className="col">
        <i className="fi fi-rr-user"></i>
      </div>
    </Link>
  </div>
</div>

 );}
    export default Menubar;
```

Comment: And what does `console.warn(user.role)` log?

Comment: I just wanted to use it to show the user role on console. And it does. The current user role is 1, it shows 1

Comment: Yeah but its crucial here - just paste here what does `console.log(user.role, typeof user.role)` logs

Comment: Maybe it's a string, hence your if checks will fail and render normal user .. if so, try using == instead of ===

Comment: is this component being rendered inside a `UserContext.Provider`? If not, you'll always get the default `role` value specified in the context definition.

Comment: Sorry, I saw something else. It logs `undefined 'undefined'`

Comment: if it is correctly inside a provider, examine how that's setting the value as the fault will be in that logic, not in the child component shown here

Comment: Okay. Its a menu component that does not need to be a Route. How do I place it correctly inside the `UserContext.Provider`

Comment: see the [examples](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useContext) here for how `useContext` works and how it interacts with the `Provider` of the appropriate context. I presume your user data is fetched from an API when your app loads - that logic needs to be in a high-level component, which then provides it to a `UserContext.Provider` which should wrap your entire app, likely including all your routes.

Answer (score 0):

One potential way to force an update on the page on context updates is to utilize the useEffect and useState hooks in conjunction with your useContext. Here is an example, I hope this helps.

For example:

```js
import React, { Component, useEffect, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Menubar.css";
import { UserContext } from "../../UserContext";

const Menubar = () => {

  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [menuContext, setMenuContext] = useState(user);

  const handleSetMenuContext = (updatedMenuContext) => {
    setMenuContext(updatedMenuContext);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleSetMenuContext(user);
  }, [user]);

return menuContext?.role && (
<div>
  <div className="appBottomMenu">

    {menuContext.role === 1 ? (
      <Link to="/admin/home" className="item" tabIndex="1">
        <div className="col">
          <i className="fi fi-rr-home"></i>
        </div>
      </Link>
    ) : (
      <Link to="/" className="item" tabIndex="1">
        <div className="col">
          <i className="fi fi-rr-home"></i>
        </div>
      </Link>
    )}

    {menuContext.role === 1 ? (
      <Link className="item" to="/admin/farmers">
        <div className="col">
          <i className="fi fi-rr-users"></i>
        </div>
      </Link>
    ) : (
      <Link to="/area" className="item" tabIndex="1">
        <div className="col">
          <i className="fi fi-rr-marker"></i>
        </div>
      </Link>
    )}

    <Link to="/community" className="item">
      <div className="col">
        <i className="fi fi-rr-browser"></i>
      </div>
    </Link>


    {menuContext.role === 1 ? (
      <Link className="item" to="/admin/farms">
        <div className="col">
          <i className="fi fi-rr-users"></i>
        </div>
      </Link>
    ) : (
      <Link to="/shop" className="item">
        <div className="col">
          <i className="fi fi-rr-shopping-cart"></i>
        </div>
      </Link>
    )}


    <Link to="/profile" className="item">
      <div className="col">
        <i className="fi fi-rr-user"></i>
      </div>
    </Link>
  </div>
</div>
);
}
export default Menubar;
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'role')`. It is a menu component that is called inside a Dashboard Component

Comment: Updated example to remove printing user.role, since that could potentially be undefined. Without seeing the dashboard component, or the code for the project's provider there isn't much more I can help with in regards to changes for your menu component. Here is an example provider setup: https://codesandbox.io/s/async-haze-gctnf0?file=/src/userContext.js